# Automatic macro replacement in the TwinCAT C++ project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, plc, twincat

C:\SXCore This file path contains header and c files that I use in multiple projects. According to the project I open, I include the relevant functions from here to my project and I use project-specific macros to make the distinction here. However, as I change the project I open, I need to change the macro manually. The file path of my project is C:\Products\SMotion\SM8000S6DEP1020IN01. Can I build a structure that can automatically change the macros I change in SXCore as the project I open differs.
[image: Sample]

As you can see in the picture, if I do the same process in each project, the problem seems to be solved, but if you look at the file path, it contains the file path of the project. I need to find a way to do this in the SXCore file path, because I think that using separate file paths for each project I open will not solve my problem.

I defined a macro to define each of the projects I opened, for example, I defined a special macro for the RobotA project and a special macro for RobotB and imported the header files to SXCore, but. In order to import them, I need to include the file path of the project I opened. Since I have more than one project and only one SXCore, what I need is a macro that changes when I open the project. In this way, I will be able to get the functions I want without making changes manually in SXCore thanks to the automatically assigned macro.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to ask, but the correct solution is to use compiler flags (`-I`) to specify the include paths.

Comment: You should change all those includes to `#include "Projectfiles/ConfigManagement/ProjectConfig.h"` and modify the include path for each project.

Comment: What I mean is that the ConfigManagement file on the left side in the picture below is a core file that I use for multiple projects, this is a separate project and I have common functions in it. As I change my project, I change the macro name of that project from here and get the functions I need. 
This is the file path of the project with core functions;

Comment: This is the file path of the project with core functions;
C:\SXCore
This file is in the way in my projects;
C:\Products
C:\Products\Robot\Robot\RobotProject01
C:\Products\Motion\MotionProject02
What I want is that when I open these projects, the following macro variable can be changed automatically in sxcore, so that no matter which project I open, the macro will change accordingly and I will be able to get the libraries and functions I want. But if this is an impossible structure, you can also say that.

Answer (score 1):

There is Preprocessor option in Project's properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor Definitions.
You could add your custom Marco for each project, such as : _MyWindows or _MyLinux.

Then in your ConfigerManagement.h:

```
#ifdef _MyWindows 
#define XXXX
#else 
#ifdef _MyLinux
#define XXXXX
#endif
```

This way you can avoid using project names but generic macros to include header files.

Comment: No not solved :(

Comment: The last thing that came to my mind was to run an .exe that will make automatic changes to the .c or .h file related to a script I wrote from pthon before opening the project.